# How to return a error code from a function which creates structures dynamically

Tags: c, pointers, struct, integer, incompatibletypeerror

I return a error code from create_node function so that if memory not available it returns to the main and the program ends. I get an error that comparison of integer to pointer. Can you please help me to deal with it. I am a beginner. Thanks.

```
node *create_node(void)
{
    node *newnode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

    if (newnode == NULL)
        return 1;
    newnode->right = NULL;
    newnode->left = NULL;
    return newnode;
}
```

```
int main(void)
{
    int ret_val = 0;
    node *root = create_node();

    if (root == 1) {
        printf("Memory not available to create a node\n");
        return 0;
    }
    root->left = create_node();
    if (root->left == 1) {
        printf("Memory not available to create a node\n");
        return 0;
    }
    root->right = create_node();
    if (root->right == 1) {
        printf("Memory not available to create a node\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered returning a `NULL` pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the C Standard (6.5.9 Equality operators) relative to comparisons of pointers and integers there is written

> 2 One of the following shall hold:
>
> — both operands have arithmetic type;
>
> — both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of
>   compatible types;
>
> — one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a
>   pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void; or
>
> — one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant.

So you may not compare a pointer and an integer without casting.

But in any case there is no need to return an integer in the case when a memory allocation will fail. In such a case it is enough to return NULL.

So the function can look like

```
node * create_node(void)
{
    node *newnode = malloc( sizeof( node ) );

    if  ( newnode != NULL )
    {
        newnode->right = NULL;
        newnode->left  = NULL;
    }

    return newnode;
}
```

Thus in main you can write for example

```
node *root = create_node();

if ( root == NULL ) {
    printf("Memory not available to create a node\n");
    return 0;
}
```

without getting the error message of the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

```
 node *root = create_node();
 if(root == 1)
```

`root` is a pointer to `node` which you compare to the `int` value of `1`. That´s why the error of comparing an integer with a pointer occurs.

It is not allowed to compare a pointer with an `int` in C. At least not if you didn´t casted the `int` to a pointer type.

---

#### Solution:

You should return a `NULL` pointer if the allocation in `create_node()` fails instead of returning `1`:

```
 node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(*newnode));

 if (newnode == NULL)
 {
     return NULL;
 }
```

And then check `root` for `NULL` in `main()`:

```
 node *root = create_node();

 if (root == NULL)
 {
     fprintf(stderr,"Memory not available to create a node\n");
     return 1;
 }
```

---

Side notes:

1. When an error occurs, the return value of `main()` shall be non-zero (`1` is common).
2. You do not need to cast the result of `malloc()`. Here is a link: [Do I cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
3. `malloc(sizeof(*newnode))` - Using this ensures that the allocated space will always fit to the object the pointer `newnode` points to (Important if you later want to change the structure pointed to by `newnode`).